# Second JQuery instruction inside HTML doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple HTML page that looks like this [html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7cCv.png) and this is the HTML code for it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tincidunt a gravida non, tincidunt condimentum nullam.
Aliquam mi augue, venenatis sed dolor eget. Aliquam venenatis felis, nullam ante est, nullam mattis massa nec nunc imperdiet convallis.</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do, is highlight every occurrence of the words "dolor" and "nullam" on the page. In order to achieve this, I have embedded the following JQuery instructions inside the HTML code, like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Tincidunt a gravida non, tincidunt condimentum nullam.
Aliquam mi augue, venenatis sed dolor eget. Aliquam venenatis felis, nullam ante est, nullam mattis massa nec nunc imperdiet convallis.</h1>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/dolor/gi, "<mark>dolor</mark>"));
 $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/nullam/gi, "<mark>nullam</mark>"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, what I find is that only the first JQuery line gets executed, that is, only the word "dolor" is highlighted, and this is what I see on the page [highlighted html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdTZ9.png). What I expect to see instead, is something like this [expected html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PytAO.png), where all occurrences of both words are highlighted. Any idea why the second JQuery line gets ignored and how I can fix it to achieve my expected result?
Thank you all.

Comment: You are replacing body and again you script runs . This forms a loop.

Comment: @NavnathJadhav I changed it to $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/dolor/gi, "<mark>dolor</mark>").replace(/nullam/gi, "<mark>nullam</mark>")); and now it works

Comment: Thats good then.. Can you share working code on jsfiddle

Comment: This is the code https://jsfiddle.net/2jbopxqg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line of that script rewrites the entire content of the `<body>` element.

This includes the `<script>` element that is doing the rewriting.

This breaks the script.

Either:

- Move it to the `<head>` and wrap it in [a DOM ready event handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).
- Change it so it only affects the relevant part of the page (e.g. add a `<main>` element).

Comment: Thank you. How would I change this $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/dolor/gi, "<mark>dolor</mark>") so that it would effect only a specific element on the page and not the entire body?

Comment: Replace the selector `body` with a selector that targets a narrow part of the page.

Comment: Thanks! I changed "body" to "h1" and now it works as expected!